# Overture error: Name 'BinBuilder()' is not in scope

Tags: vdm++

I've been doing the exercises of a book focused on iteratively building a whole application. After having written four classes, I'm writing my fifth which is a test for the fourth one. However, Overture is reporting a "Name 'BinBuilder()' is not in scope" error; BinBuilder is the last class I successfully wrote. I cannot figure out what I'm doing differently this time. BinBuilder is not the only class causing problems, two other are too. Since I don't know what's wrong, I'm including a [link](http://sabercathost.com/53f/Roulette.zip) to the whole thing here. Thank you.

EDIT: It links a zip file exported from Overture and it includes a screen capture showing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following:

```
builder: BinBuilder := BinBuilder();
```

But I think you mean:

```
builder: BinBuilder := new BinBuilder();
```

The "not in scope" error means "I can't find a function or operation call of that name in scope". It's not a great error message, I'm afraid. Overture and VDMJ use the same "not in scope" message for when a name does not exist anywhere and for when it does exist, but is not visible within the current scope. In this case, the syntax causes it to look for a func/op call rather than a class name.

Comment: D***! Thanks Nick. Such a stupid error! I have found it many times and corrected it, and now I missed it.

Comment: LOL, it's easily done. And as I said, the error message could be more helpful.